# When should I use 'className' over 'class' and vise versa in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, class, classname

I'm making my first react app and i've come across something interesting, I sometimes use `className` over `class` on react. I'm just wondering if they are interchangeable or is it like this for a reason? I also notice that when I use `class` the inspect elements console asks me if I meant `className`, no errors, just asks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname):

> To specify a CSS class, use the className attribute. This applies to
>   all regular DOM and SVG elements like `<div>`, `<a>`, and others.
>
> If you use React with Web Components (which is uncommon), use the
>   class attribute instead.

If you use `class` as an attribute, it is passed down without any validation to the underlying dom element, but it is not preferred approach. `className` is an attribute understood by react.

React docs recommend on using `cannonical React attribute` names rather than the conventional Javascript naming, so even when React allows attributes to be passed through to DOM, it will give you a warning.

Answer (score 1):

It's yet another "feature" to recognize unknown DOM attributes.

> In the past, React used to ignore unknown DOM attributes. If you wrote JSX with an attribute that React doesn’t recognize, React would just skip it.

It [has changed](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html#why-are-we-changing-this) from `React 16` and gives a warning. The way you use DOM components in React hasn’t changed, but now you have some new capabilities.

> React has always provided a JavaScript-centric API to the DOM. Since React components often take both custom and DOM-related props, it makes sense for React to use the camelCase convention just like the DOM APIs

As for [`className`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname):

> To specify a CSS class, use the className attribute. This applies to all regular DOM and SVG elements like `<div>`, `<a>`, and others.
>
> If you use React with Web Components (which is uncommon), use the class attribute instead.

See [Specifying Attributes with JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx):

> Since JSX is closer to JavaScript than to HTML, React DOM uses camelCase property naming convention instead of HTML attribute names.
>
> For example, class becomes className in JSX, and tabindex becomes tabIndex.